# What columns are needed to list the database, schema and table a record comes from?

Tags: postgresql, schema, metadata, catalogs

I am writing queries which read identical tables across databases and schemas and I need the columns to include which schema and table a row comes from.

While searching during the creation of this post I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576324)

```
SELECT u.*, n.nspname as schema, u.tableoid::regclass::text as table_or_view
FROM   uses u
JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.oid = u.tableoid
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
```

This now includes the schema and the table or view.

What joins do I need now to add the database as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) can help:

> `current_catalog` → `name`
>
> `current_database ()` → `name`
>
> Returns the name of the current database. (Databases are called “catalogs” in the SQL standard, so current_catalog is the standard's spelling.)

Comment: Is there a standard name used by SQL database servers to refer to what PostgreSQL calls a `catalog`?

Answer (score 1):

Get the database name with [`current_database()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE) like mustaccio provided.

Your column alias "table_or_view" indicates you plan to use this for views also, but **[`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)s don't have a `tableoid`**. (Except for [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html)s, which are built around actual physical tables as opposed to plain views.)

**If** you are going to join to `pg_class` anyway, it makes more sense to output `pg_class.relname` directly, rather than casting the `tableoid`:

```
SELECT current_database() AS db
     , n.nspname          AS schema
     , c.relname          AS table_or_view
     , u.*
FROM   uses u
JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.oid = u.tableoid
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid;
```

**If** this is just for tables (and no views), you can use `u.tableoid::regclass::text`. And you don't need joins to more tables.

The output is only schema-qualified if the current [schema search path `search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) would require it. To output the schema name always, set an empty `search_path` for the query. But then you have to schema-qualify your table to find it:

```
SET search_path =  '';
SELECT current_database() AS db
     , u.tableoid::regclass::text AS schema_and_table
     , *
FROM   public.uses u;  -- schema-qualified table name!
```

You'll want to keep your current `search_path`. You could reset it after the query. But rather just set it locally for the query to begin with:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL search_path = '';  -- SET LOCAL!
SELECT current_database() AS db
     , u.tableoid::regclass::text AS schema_and_table
     , *
FROM   public.uses u;  -- schema-qualified table name!

ROLLBACK;   -- or COMMIT; doesn't matter while you just SELECT;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html)

> The effects of `SET LOCAL` last only till the end of the current transaction, whether committed or not.